# Netezza correlated query

Tags: sybase, netezza, correlated-subquery

I am migrating from Sybase to Netezza and Netezza does not support this type of query. Can someone show me how to rewrite it?

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
SET t1.col1=t2.col1
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.col2=t2.col2
AND t2.col3=(SELECT MAX(t3.col3) FROM table2 t3 WHERE t3.col2=t1.col2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of correlated subquery will actually work in Netezza depending on your version.

I happen to be running 7.2, and it works just fine.

```
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzrev
Release 7.2.0.3 [Build 42210]
[nz@netezza ~]$ k^C
[nz@netezza ~]$ set -o vi
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzsql -d testdb
Welcome to nzsql, the IBM Netezza SQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help on internal slash commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> UPDATE table1 t1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> SET t1.col1=t2.col1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> FROM table2 t2
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> WHERE t1.col2=t2.col2
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> AND t2.col3=(SELECT MAX(t3.col3) FROM table2 t3 WHERE t3.col2=t1.col2);
UPDATE 1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=>
```

Less recent versions (pre 7.1) won't handle that, though. Here is how you couldrewrite that particular case as a join rather than a correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.col1=t2.col1
FROM table2 t2,
   (
      SELECT col2,
         MAX(col3) col3
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY col2
   )
   t3
WHERE t1.col2 = t2.col2
AND t2.col2  = t3.col2
AND t2.col3  = t3.col3;
```

The [documentation for v7.2.0](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_correlated_subqueries_ntz_sql.html?lang=en) has this to say about correlated subquery support.

> If you choose to use correlated subqueries, keep in mind the following
>   restrictions on the form and placement of correlated subqueries:
>
> You can use correlated subqueries in WHERE clauses.
>
> You can use correlated subqueries in inner join conditions and with the equal join condition operator.
>
> You can use correlated subqueries in mixed correlated expressions only in the following form:
>
> ```
>     expr(corr_columA, corr_columnB,...) = expr(local_columnX, local_columnY,...)
> ```
>
> You cannot use correlated subqueries in SET operations (UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT, and MINUS).
>
> You cannot use correlated subqueries in aggregates with GROUP BY and HAVING clauses.
>
> You cannot use correlated subqueries in ORed clauses or in CASE/WHEN expressions.
>
> You cannot use correlated subqueries in IN lists. You cannot use correlated subqueries in SELECT lists.

Comment: Version im working on is 6.0 seems quite old. Im getting lots of trouble with theese correlated subqueries.
Would updating to latest version would solve theese correlation type of issues ?

Comment: The support for correlated subqueries is much, much, much better in recent versions. I can't say it will fix all of the issues, but it covers a lot of cases I've run into.  Updating my answer to includes some details from the documentation.